# Progress, circular progress and image component is not showing on cv while using jsPDF

Tags: pdf-generation, jspdf, react-pdf

I am developing a **CV** maker website in react-js. for generating pdf I am using **Jspdf dependency**. but the problem is that jsPdf not rendering some components on cv after generating pdf. These components are **progress, circular progress, and image**. I also used **react to pdf**, **print pdf.** Both have the same issue.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.